# Тире или запятая?2

Tags: пунктуация

*Для организации услуги за наличный расчет (-/,) сообщить стоимость работы бригады в час.*

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Для организации услуги за наличный расчет ― сообщить стоимость работы бригады в час.

**Постановка тире возможна, но зависит от контекста**,  от структуры предыдущего предложения. В общем случае лучше использовать фразу без тире: Для организации услуги за наличный расчет **необходимо** сообщить стоимость работы бригады в час.